# ethers.js library version to use to learn Ethereum development

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, javascript, bignumber, viem

Which version of the Ethers.js library, either v5 or v6, is recommended for me to learn and work with? I'm seeking advice on which version would be more beneficial for my current needs and future projects. Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Neither. I would recommend using [Viem](https://viem.sh/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

For learning ethers.js, it would be better to learn the latest version, v6 currently.

v6 allows you to also learn built-in ES2020 BigInt.

> One of the biggest changes in v6 is that the BigNumber class has been replaced with the built-in ES2020 BigInt offered by modern JavaScript environments.

Because v5 didn't use the built-in BigInt, it ended up using a library, where the chances of bugs are higher, such as https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/3017

Comment: I fully concur, but for the purposes of readers who find this in the future, I'll add that in general I would recommend always using the latest version unless there's a specific reason not too

Comment: @TheRenaissance Agree. Readers should also know that older versions are unlikely to get any more updates or bug fixes, if any.